# Draw a venn diagram showing an event along with its sufficient and necessary conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider some event $S$ along with:

- $S_n$ (Necessary events for $S$)
- $S_s$ (Sufficient events for $S$)
- $S_{ns}$ (Necessary and sufficient events for $S$)

Draw a Venn diagram indicating the above.

This is my attempt:

[image: Venn_diagram]

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track and I also don't know where to indicate $S_{ns}$ (necessary and sufficient).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes of events are not all going to be nested in one another. Rather, you can have two ‘circles’ representing $S_{sufficient}$ and $S_{necessary}$, and their intersection, $(S_s\cap S_n)$ is going to be the set of necessary and sufficient events. Clearly then, the event S is fully captured by the set $S_s$.